# Applocale alternative for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, locale

Looks like Applocale is developed before Windows Vista UAC and has many compatibility issues. Even after successfully installed, it still doesn't work for some of the programs. So I was wondering if there's any alternative for lacale issue in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppLocale is not supported under anything but XP and 2003, but here's a potential workaround...

From [How to Install Microsoft AppLocale in Windows 7](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-install-microsoft-applocale-in-windows-7/):

> ...here is another workaround that do not need you to take security risk by disabling UAC.
>
> 1. Run an elevated command prompt by right clicking on Command Prompt on Start Menu and then select “Run as Administrator”.
> 2. Click on Continue when User Account Control dialog prompt comes out.
> 3. Change directory to the folder where you put the apploc.msi Windows Installer Package.
> 4. Type apploc.msi to start the setup.
> 5. The AppLocale installation will complete successfully.

This should work for Windows 7 as well.

Additionally, to prevent troubles when running stuff via AppLocale ("AppLocale was unable to launch the specified application.  Please make sure the application specified is valid.") you'll have to [set it to always run as an administrator](http://www.mydigitallife.info/workaround-to-run-non-unicode-legacy-setup-or-installer-with-applocale-in-vista/):

> To set AppLoc.exe to run as administrator permanently, simply right click on AppLoc.exe executable, select Properties. Then click on Compatibility tab, and finally tick the check box for Run this program as an administrator option under "Privilege Level" section. Click OK when done.

Also, depending on your version of Windows 7, you can also change the [Change the display language](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-display-language) settings to the language you desire:

> 1. Open Regional and Language Options by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Clock, Language, and Region, and then clicking Regional and Language Options.
> 2. Click the Keyboards and Languages tab.
> 3. Under Display language, choose a language from the list, and then click OK.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is [SteelBytes's AppLocale](http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=45).  It's command line driven, which is convenient for scripting, and it also lacks the nag screen that Microsoft's AppLocale has.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Applocale in a XP VM.

Comment: Yes, but if you're running a VM, you can have it in the language you want...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to run one or more applications in a different language of the system default.

For that you could use a different user of the system to run that applications you need in a different language.

- Create a new local user.
- Log in with that user and change the Windows language of that account to the other language you need.
- Log out
- Log in with your usual user.
- Run the application you want to see in a different language with the "Run As" method (shift+right click on the application, and select Run as different User).

Comment: Done! I went directly to the solution, sorry!