# Run Windows application with different locale setting

Tags: windows, locale

I have a badly written third-party Windows application that only works correctly if the decimal separator and thousands grouping characters are set to the values typical for English, i.e. point for decimal, comma for thousands. This application is used by a number of users with different user locales, some of which (e.g. German) swap these characters for each other.

Is there a way to run this application with its desired locale configuration, without changing it globally and so that the user does not have to do anything difficult?

I have found things like AppLocale and Locale Emulator, but they appear a bit too broad for my purpose – I don't want to change the whole language etc., just the two characters.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There are several third-party applications that allow you to do this.  **The list of related questions is a good start.**  I will not recommend a specific solution for obvious reasons.

Comment: None of the workarounds (can't really call them solutions) I have found work without demanding far too difficult things from the user, not least understanding what the problem actually is. I'm in a situation where the users neither want to know the background nor have time to learn it, and certainly don't have time to deal with a password prompt (in a console window!) each time they start that particular application (which can be two dozen times a day – and they won't let themselves be instructed to just leave it running, either).

Comment: You asked if it was possible, it is indeed possible, how well it works depends on the program itself.  Regional localization in an application can be done several ways if the program is poorly designed then the solutions in the duplicate nor any similar solution cannot be used.  You might not call them solutions, but at least one [program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppLocale) is indeed a solution.  *It sounds like you should find a different third-party program.*  **This question is still a duplicate.**

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/318026/applocale-alternative-for-windows-7 and https://superuser.com/questions/905522/how-to-launch-a-64-bit-program-with-a-different-locale-than-the-system-locale